# Cisco Packet Tracer Hub IP

Tags: ip, cisco, subnet, vlan

So I have the following topology.

[image]

The problem that I'm facing has to do with the labeling above the hub's. I tried every possible hub in Packet Tracer and none of them had the configuration for IP. My guess is that the IP given is the IP of a VLAN or a Subnet. Can someone confirm me this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Repeater hubs are very simple devices. Managed ones are very rare and unmanaged ones don't use any IP address.

You should note that hubs are long obsolete and shouldn't be used. Use a switch instead.